# Drawing an image w/ canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am really new to drawing images with canvas in JavaScript. What I have is a byte array of values for an image. This byte array in my case is 144000 bytes long (720w x 200h image), each byte is a single 8-bit pixel intensity data. This image is also grayscale. I have code to draw the image but for some reason it replicates the photo 4 times and is really hard to see (white washed).

Here is my code:

```
var str = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer, { stream: true });
const img = new Image();
var context = this.htmlcanvaselement.getContext("2d");
var imgdata = context?.getImageData(0, 0, 720, 200);
if (imgdata !== undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.byteLength; i++) {
         var num = str.charCodeAt(i) / 3;
         imgdata.data[i] = num;       //R
         imgdata.data[i + 1] = num;   //G
         imgdata.data[i + 2] = num;   //B
         imgdata.data[i + 3] = 255;   //Alpha
    }
    context?.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
}
```

What I get is the same image 4 times next to each-other horizontally. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

edit:

I realize now that the image data length is 4x the source size, I need 1 byte for each RGBA. I have updated my code to:

```
const str = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer, { stream: true });
const img = new Image();
const context = this.ibcs.getContext("2d");
const imgdata = context?.getImageData(0, 0, 720, 200);
if (imgdata !== undefined) {
   for (let i = 0; i < buffer.byteLength; i++) {
       let num = str.charCodeAt(i) / 3;
       imgdata.data[i * 4 + 0] = num;
       imgdata.data[i * 4 + 1] = num;
       imgdata.data[i * 4 + 2] = num;
       imgdata.data[i * 4 + 3] = 185;
   }
   context?.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
}
```

What I am experiencing now is that the drawn image looks more pixelated than my source and looks like it contains significantly less detail. might have to do with the HtmlImageElement rendering for different sizes.

Comment: Two quick things: 1) It would be helpful if you could post a working snippet that illustrates the issue; it will be easier for the community to debug and troubleshoot, and thus easier for us to assist you; and 2) You should avoid mixing `var` containers into modern code.  Use `const` if the variable is never to be reassigned and `let` if it can be reassigned.  Looking at the code above, at a glance, it seems like you could potentially use `const` for all these variables.

Comment: The index into `imgdata.data` needs a stride of 4, but the index into `str`, needs a stride of 1. One way to solve this is using something like `imgdata.data[i*4+n]` (where `n` is 0 through 3).

Comment: thanks for that, I actually just figured that out about 20 minutes ago, i just didn't understand the Image() api. I am getting an image now but for some reason it looks somewhat pixelated compared to the original. will update post.